# Can I set the Launcher to close on mouseout

Tags: unity, launcher

Currently, I have to hit the super key again to close it.  Is there a setting to close it once focus is no longer on it?

Comment: Seems that the upgrading to 14.10 made this better. If I type a term in the lens, then click on an app on a different monitor, it auto hides.  But not if I click on an app on the same monitor as the open lens.

Comment: Just confirming, the Dash will not close when I click on an app behind it.  I'm on three monitors with the Dash on the middle one.  Clicking on the left or right monitor will close it, but not the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

That should be default(?)

This hides the launcher when the cursor is NOT at the left side of the screen:

[image]

Comment: The launcher does auto hide with the setting enabled, if I launch an app from it.  If I just hit the super key to open the launcher, then move the mouse to the browser and start typing, focus is kept on the launcher and my keystrokes are rendered there.  I have to hit the super key again to steal focus back.

Comment: If there's no search term in the lens, then focusing else where allows it to hide.  Otherwise, I have to remove the term, or hit the super key again.